# extraData flatlist prop in functional component?

Tags: javascript, react-native

When using a class component with a FlatList I know that to get a re-render you need to use extraData-{this.state}

I am using a functional component with Hooks. I have a state

```
const [selectedGuests, setSelectedGuests] = useState([]);
```

and a Flatlist

```
<FlatList
    data={contactsData}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    extraData={selectedGuests}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    >
```

but when I change the state's array nothing changes. Well, it works if I add an item but not when deleting an item from the array so I am assuming that the extraData is not working as I have it at the moment.

What I am trying to do is to change the background colour of an item in a FlatList to show that it was selected. It works if I add the item id to an array:

```
<View style={{ other style stuff then.. backgroundColor: selectedGuests.find(k => k === item.id) ? "#ffe5e5" : "#eee"}}
```

Then in the function called by clicking a button to select the item

```
const addToList = (guestIDnum) => {
  const guestArray = selectedGuests;
  guestArray.push(guestIDnum);
  const mySortedList = guestArray.sort();
  const sortedNoDupes = Array.from(new Set(mySortedList));
  setSelectedGuests(sortedNoDupes);
}
```

Which works. Removing items is like so:

```
const removeFromList = (guestIDnum) => {
  const guestArray = selectedGuests;
  const itemIndex = guestArray.indexOf(guestIDnum);
  if (itemIndex > -1) {
    guestArray.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    setSelectedGuests(guestArray);
  }
}
```

While I can see in the console that items are being added and removed, the colour changes only when an item is added, or if I remove one item then select a new one the screen re-renders correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you `const guestArray = selectedGuests;` means you point `guestArray` to `selectedGuests`, so they are pointing to the same array (location). When  deleting an item, you are actually manipulate `selectedGuests` then call `setSelectedGuests(guestArray);`, it will not re-render because the array location is not change (that are how React update state and re-render, shallowly compare object)
Try this:

```js
const removeFromList = (guestIDnum) => {
  // Clone guestArray
  const guestArray = [...selectedGuests];
  const itemIndex = guestArray.indexOf(guestIDnum);
  if (itemIndex > -1) {
    guestArray.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    setSelectedGuests(guestArray);
  }
}
```